# Delete all rows in a python numpy array that do not correspond to the top n values of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following array with 2 columns. I would like to determine the top 3 highest values in the second column and delete all rows that do not include the value in the top 3.

```
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 2]])
```

output:

```
array([[2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [1, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, the sorting needs to be done only on the 2nd column, you can use `pandas`. It makes the stuff a bit easier:

```
import pandas

In [725]: x
Out[725]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [2, 4]])

In [724]: pd.DataFrame(x).sort_values(1, ascending=False).head(3).values.tolist()
Out[724]: [[2, 5], [3, 5], [1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy argsort and take the last 3 rows

```
array_name[np.argsort(array_name, axis = 0)[:,1]][-3:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code that might help you

```
x  = ([[0, 3],[1, 4],[2, 5],[3, 5],[4, 2]])

f = sorted(x, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(f[2:])
```

From [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) link

Answer (score 0):

Although I do agree with Anagnostou John, I propose changing it like this:

```
a  = np.array([[0, 3],
               [1, 4],
               [2, 5],
               [3, 5],
               [4, 2]])

f = sorted(a, key=lambda x: -x[1])
print(f[:3])
```

Because this can be used for bigger arrays as well.